# Python Pandas if statement based on group by sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Working with this python pandas dataframe df:

```
CategoryA | CategoryB | Count
1           A           0
1           A           -1
2           B           1
2           B           1
3           C           1
3           C           -1
```

I basically want to mark for deletion, all groupings of CategoryA/B whose sum is lower than 0.

```
df['decision'] = np.where(df.groupby(['CategoryA', 'CategoryB'])['Count'].sum()>0, 'keep', 'delete')
```

But I get this error **ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index**

Output would be:

```
CategoryA | CategoryB | Count | decision
1           A           0       delete
1           A           -1      delete
2           B           1       keep
2           B           1       keep
3           C           1       delete
3           C           -1      delete
```

Would prefer to do this with df.loc, but not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [67]: df['decision'] = \
             np.where(df.groupby(['CategoryA', 'CategoryB'])['Count'].transform('sum') > 0, 
                      'keep', 'delete')

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
   CategoryA CategoryB  Count decision
0          1         A      0   delete
1          1         A     -1   delete
2          2         B      1     keep
3          2         B      1     keep
4          3         C      1   delete
5          3         C     -1   delete
```

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track.

```
m = df.groupby(['CategoryA', 'CategoryB']).transform('sum').gt(0)
df['decision'] = np.where(m, 'keep', 'delete')

df
   CategoryA CategoryB  Count decision
0          1         A      0   delete
1          1         A     -1   delete
2          2         B      1     keep
3          2         B      1     keep
4          3         C      1   delete
5          3         C     -1   delete
```

Use `transform` to retrieve a result with the same size.

Comment: thank you - getting this error TypeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object is not callable

Answer (score 3):

```
df['decision']=df['CategoryB'].map(df.groupby('CategoryB')['Count'].\
      apply(lambda x :np.where(x.sum()>0,'keep','delete')))
df
Out[573]: 
   CategoryA CategoryB  Count decision
0          1         A      0   delete
1          1         A     -1   delete
2          2         B      1     keep
3          2         B      1     keep
4          3         C      1   delete
5          3         C     -1   delete
```